# Android InApp billing wrapper?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is there any well tested and documented wrapper around InApp Billing API?

What Google provides is even hard to call an API - single `aidl` interface, and a fairly complex (for the task) sample application. Not to mention, there are known bugs not yet fixed (e.g. not checking for `null` in `BillingService.onStart()`)  Pretty confusing...

I've sort of integrated the payments process based on the sample application, but I'm looking for some better solution. What I've found so far:

- [gumma-android-payments](http://code.google.com/p/gumma-android-payments/) - this one provides fair API, but implementation seems to be just copy of `Dungeons` sample, which doesn't make me feel safe using it
- [marketbilling](http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/) - this seems to be the Dungeon sample application project on Google Code (current trunk doesn't event compile - no comments)

Are there any other recommended resources (beside the official docs, of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Android Billing Library](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary)

Comment: Thanks, it looks much better at least at first sight, gonna give it a try!